# Keep the map straight with arcgis projections

Tags: arcmap, dem, georeferencing, distortion, historical-maps

I need to overlap DEM file with an historical map.
The historical map doesn't have georeferencing so I need to add some control points, but when I do this the map is distorted.

There is a way to distort only the DEM file so the historical map doesn't change?
Can I distort the DEM and keep the map as the original?

Here's an example:
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to distort a correct DEM, how was the historical map was georeferenced, and how were the control points added(referenced from) can you add a screenshot of the historical map.

Comment: Do you mean historical aerial photography? If this is the case you cannot apply classical georeferencing options to your data since it   doesn't have uniform scale at each pixel.

Comment: The historical map is not georeferenced, here the map: http://www.davidrumsey.com/ll/thumbnailView.html?startUrl=%2F%2Fwww.davidrumsey.com%2Fluna%2Fservlet%2Fas%2Fsearch%3Fos%3D0%26q%3DList_No%3D1603.112%26bs%3D10#?c=0&m=0&s=0&cv=0&r=0&xywh=-427%2C-1613%2C8533%2C8533

Comment: You could try reprojecting the DEM (to a copy). The linked vintage map has converging longitude lines, your screen shot does not, so they are not in the same projection. That is only one of issues I see.